# What does "really" mean in this?

Tags: meaning

What does "really" mean in this scenario?

A: "I don't really know much about the subject so I can't really help you."

1st really means?

2nd really means?

Context:

Person B wants Person A to promote his youtube channel, but Person A does not use any of the "promoting sites" but one that's not very good.

Person B: Can you help me promote my channel?

Person A: I can't really help you as I don't use reddit, only discord, which is not that good.

Comment: "I can't help you" sounds rather blunt, as though the speaker doesn't want to even try to help. _Really_ is a fairly meaningless filler which softens the statement, implying something like "I would help, but what knowledge I have is not at all relevant."

Comment: The "Really" here is used to mean *"Actually"*. which is to emphasize the inability or unwillingness to help.

Comment: I'd say it is repetitious to use *really* twice in a sentence.